# How to know when a program is open with javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a problem, i want to know when a program is open with javascript.This is possible?

Comment: Open, as in open-source?

Comment: could you rephrase your question? it's hard to understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume, that you mean JavaScript running in a browser and by program you mean an real application running on the clients operating system (such as bash, vim or emacs).

Then this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about javascript running inside a browser?  No, that's not possible.  Javascript running in a browser is not allowed to interact with the host OS for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you implement said program with a javascript parser.

If you're talking about from the browser, the answer is a resounding no. That would be a massive security risk. If you had the application you want to check on report when it's active to a server that you can query with javascript, that would work, but if you don't have access to the program itself, then no.